# update with invalid attributes re-renders :new template instead of :edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this action in controller:

```
  def update
    @board = Board.find(params[:board_id])
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.update_attributes(category_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You sucessfully changed category name."
      redirect_to settings_board_path(@board)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

And problem with this test case:

```
context "with invalid attributes" do
  let(:updated_category) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:category, name: "") }

  it "re-renders :edit template" do
    patch :create, board_id: board, id: category, category: updated_category
    expect(response).to render_template :edit 
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <["categories/new", "layouts/application"]>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is calling `patch :create`, not `patch :update`, so it's running the wrong action entirely.